# How to delete one row from a table and multiple rows on another that are related?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have two tables:

#### Images

```
post_id     user_id     post_text     post_time
----------------------------------------------------------
1           1           TEXT          2014-01-12 11:07:00
2           2           TEXT          2014-01-12 12:10:00
```

#### Clicked

```
clicked_id        post_id        user_id 
-----------------------------------------
1                 1              1       
2                 1              2       
3                 2              1
```

Whenever an image is clicked, with ajax, I am adding such click to the clicked table and relate it to the user that clicked the image and the post whose click came from. This is just what the tables are used for.

**The real question is:**

I delete pictures older than the **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** of the server** using an event that runs on a minute-ly manner. How to **also** delete the **clicks** that are associated with such image via the post_id of both tables?

This is the event that is currently runnning, only deleting the images older than the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP:

```
DELETE * FROM images WHERE post_time <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

**the date of the posts are set to a future date

Can someone lead me in the right way please? That would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Best way to do this **ALTER TABLE  `your_table` ADD CONSTRAINT `delete_image_clicks` 
FOREIGN KEY (`picture_id`) 
REFERENCES `clicks_table`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;**

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid, that is beyond what I have learned on my own. Can you elaborate as to what this will do please?

Comment: You are trying to delete the references of the single picture ,use cascade delete [*Read MySQL ON DELETE CASCADE Deletes Data From Multiple Tables*](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/),you need to alter your pictures table and define foreign key to clicks table with cascade delete ,so when you try to delete picture mysql will take care to delete the clicks of picture to be deleted

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid, thank you so much. That article helped me do the trick, thank you again.

Comment: You can also use a join

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @CurTime datetime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

    delete from C
    from Images I 
    join Clicked C
    on C.post_ID = I.post_ID
    where I.post_time <= @CurTime

    delete from Images 
    where post_time <= @CurTime
```

It is true for MS SQL. Dont tried in MySQL